# How to check net connection when i connected to mobile hotspot iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I have integrated `rechability.swift`. It is working fine when wifi is connected, but I want to test a  scenario like when I'm connected to a mobile (hotSpot with no internet connection). When this code always executes like connected, because the status is connected with wifi, but I need to check if the network is available or not. Any other way to do as standard way ? Please help.

```
using rechability same result

    let reachability: Reachability
    do {
        // reachability = try Reachability.NetworkReachable()

        reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

        if (reachability.isReachableViaWiFi()) {
            _label.text = "wifi connected"
        }
        else if (reachability.isReachable()) {
            _label.text = "reachable"
        }

        else if (reachability.isReachableViaWWAN()) {
            _label.text = "connected via wan"

        }
        else {
            _label.text = "not connected "
        }
    } catch {
        print("Unable to create Reachability")
        return
    }
```

Other code I used gave me the same result:

```
  func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

  var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
  zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
  zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
  let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
  }
  var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
  if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags)    {
    return false
  }
  let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
  let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
  //    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
  //    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue &   UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
  return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
 }
```

Comment: Please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx